# Update states when web socket returns a response - React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket

I'm creating a panel to manage my messages on Whatsapp, like a CRM, but I want that when a user changes his task automatically all other users who were viewing the same message panel update the components, and that's why I'm using a web socket, but I am having difficulties when changing the state of items.

```
      "use client";

  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
  import Card from "./card";
  import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";
  import socketIO from "socket.io-client";

  const Kanban = (props) => {
    const socket = socketIO.connect("http://localhost:8080");

    const height = props.height;
    const width = props.width;

    const userID = getCookie("user_id");

    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(undefined);

    {
      /* LOAD TICKETS */
    }

    function filterItems(data, status) {
      if (data !== null) {
        if (data.filter((item) => item.status === status).length !== 0) {
          return data.filter((item) => item.status === status);
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    }

    const ColumnsBase = (data) => {
      setColumns({
        [1]: {
          title: "Automatização",
          description: undefined,
          items: filterItems(data, 1),
          isDropDisabled: true,
          isInitiateChat: false,
          isViewChat: false,
        },
        [2]: {
          title: "Na fila de espera",
          description: undefined,
          items: filterItems(data, 2),
          isDropDisabled: false,
          isInitiateChat: true,
          isViewChat: false,
        },
        [3]: {
          title: "Em atendimento",
          description: undefined,
          items: filterItems(data, 3),
          isDropDisabled: false,
          isInitiateChat: false,
          isViewChat: true,
        },
      });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      socket.emit("load tickets", {
        userID: userID,
      });
      socket.on("tickets is here", (data) => ColumnsBase(data));
    }, []);

    const handleColums = (result, columns, setColumns) => {
      if (!result.destination) return;
      const { source, destination } = result;
      if (source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId) {
        const sourceColumn = columns[source.droppableId];
        const destColumn = columns[destination.droppableId];
        const sourceItems = [...sourceColumn.items];
        const destItems = [...destColumn.items];
        const [removed] = sourceItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        destItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        socket.emit("update ticket", {
          userID: userID,
          id: result.draggableId,
          status: destination.droppableId,
        });

        socket.emit("update ticket", {
          userID: userID,
          id: result.draggableId,
          status: destination.droppableId,
        });

        setColumns({
          ...columns,
          [source.droppableId]: {
            ...sourceColumn,
            items: sourceItems,
          },
          [destination.droppableId]: {
            ...destColumn,
            items: destItems,
          },
        });
      } else {
        const column = columns[source.droppableId];
        const copiedItems = [...column.items];
        const [removed] = copiedItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        copiedItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        setColumns({
          ...columns,
          [source.droppableId]: {
            ...column,
            items: copiedItems,
          },
        });
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      socket.on("updated ticket", (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }, [socket, columns]);

    return (
      <DragDropContext
        onDragEnd={(result) => handleColums(result, columns, setColumns)}
      >
        <div className="w-full flex items-center justify-between mt-10">
          {columns !== undefined &&
            Object.entries(columns)
              .filter((i) => i[1].title === "Automatização")
              .map(([columnId, column], index) => {
                return (
                  <Droppable key={columnId} droppableId={columnId} isDropDisabled>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <div
                        style={{ height: height / 1.3, width: width / 4 }}
                        className="bg-white rounded-[32px] p-10"
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.droppableProps}
                      >
                        <h1 className="text-black text-2xl">{column.title}</h1>
                        <p className="text-gray-400 text-xs">
                          {column.description}
                        </p>
                        <div className="w-full h-px bg-gray-200 mt-3" />
                        <div
                          className="overflow-auto scrollbar-hide"
                          style={{ height: height / 1.5 }}
                        >
                          {column.items.length !== 0 &&
                            column.items.map((item, index) => (
                              <Card
                                key={item}
                                item={item}
                                index={index}
                                column={column}
                              />
                            ))}
                          {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Droppable>
                );
              })}

          {columns !== undefined &&
            Object.entries(columns)
              .filter((i) => i[1].title !== "Automatização")
              .map(([columnId, column], index) => {
                return (
                  <Droppable key={columnId} droppableId={columnId}>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <div
                        style={{ height: height / 1.3, width: width / 4 }}
                        className="bg-white rounded-[32px] p-10"
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.droppableProps}
                      >
                        <h1 className="text-black text-2xl">{column.title}</h1>
                        <p className="text-gray-400 text-xs">
                          {column.description}
                        </p>
                        <div className="w-full h-px bg-gray-200 mt-3" />
                        <div
                          className="overflow-auto scrollbar-hide"
                          style={{ height: height / 1.5 }}
                        >
                          {column.items.length !== 0 &&
                            column.items.map((item, index) => (
                              <Card
                                key={item}
                                item={item}
                                index={index}
                                column={column}
                              />
                            ))}
                          {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Droppable>
                );
              })}
        </div>
      </DragDropContext>
    );
  };

  export default Kanban;
```

My Node.JS server:

```
      const express = require("express");
  const connectDb = require("./config/dbConnection");
  const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandler");
  const cors = require("cors");
  const Chat = require("./models/chat");

  const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  const app = express();
  const http = require("http").Server(app);
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  connectDb();

  //Routes
  app.use("/auth", require("./routes/authentication"));
  app.use("/chat", require("./routes/chat"));
  app.use("/time", require("./routes/functions/time"));
  app.use("/suporte", require("./routes/functions/time"));
  app.use(errorHandler);

  http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`✅ Servidor funcionando perfeitamente na rota: ${port}`);
  });

  const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
    },
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("load tickets", async ({ userID }) => {
      try {
        const chats = await Chat.find({ user_id: userID });
        socket.join(userID);

        if(userID !== undefined) {
          if (chats !== []) {
            socket.emit("tickets is here", chats);
          } else {
            socket.emit("tickets is here", null);
          }
        } else {
          socket.emit("tickets is here", null);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });


    socket.on("update ticket", async ({ userID, id, status }) => {
      try {
        const chats = await Chat.find({ user_id: userID });

        const updatedChat = await Chat.findOneAndUpdate(
          { numero: id },
          {
            "status": status,
          },
          {
            new: false,
          }
        );
        
        if(userID !== undefined && chats !== []) {
          socket.to(userID).emit('updated ticket', chats);
          return updatedChat;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    console.log(`⚡: ${socket.id} user just connected!`);
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(": A user disconnected");
    });
  });
```

Comment: could you clarify what problems you face when changing the state of items?